# Map of/Measure of conflicted areas throughout history

Tags: war, maps

I am looking for a map which would give an indication of how much territorial conflict there was in a given area. One way I imagined one could do it is to look at how territorial states (in the period where those make sense) have changed over the time. Does anybody know if maps like this exist or suggestions on how to make it in a meaningful way?

Edit notice: Thanks for all your very good comments - I have tried to address them.

Old Question: I am looking for a map of Europe which displays the number of times every area was taken over since year 1000. For example the current England was only taken over once in 1066 and therefore that area should have the value 1 etc. Do you know if such a map exists?

Comment: Cross-posted from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374621/map-showing-the-number-of-times-an-area-in-europe-was-occupied-in-history

Comment: Hi Frederik and welcome.  For the purpose of this question how are you defining "taken over"/"occupied".  Certainly the government of England was over thrown many many more times since 1066.  Please add your clarification to your question.

Comment: 1066 is before the era of the nation-state.  To your average English peasant of the time, it meant very little who had the crown so to say a "country" was "occupied" is meaningless in that context.

Comment: Also keep in mind that whether a particular border area was "England" or "Scotland" changed quite often.  Do you want that granularity?  Also, for something like Calais, was that "Occupied France" or part of the English King's territories?  Shall we refight the 100 years war on Stack Exchange? :-P

Comment: Thanks! I am mainly interested in a rough model. And yes for border areas that which changes often it would be nice to have large values.  And also an area like Calais would be very interesting. I conclusion I am interested in any map with any of the definitions that you are rightfully pointing out are unclear.

Comment: @Frederick Ravn Klausen Didn't the future king Henry II invade England a few times and eventually get King Stephen to agree to make Henry Stephen's heir?  Didn't the future KIng Louis VIII of France invade England and have a lot of success in being recognized as king for a few years?  Didn't Queen Isabella and Roger Mortimer Invade England  and depose king Endward II?  Didn't Henry IV and Henry VII invade England and depose Richard II and Richard III respectively?  Didn't William III invade England and depose James II? I think your opinion that England was only takenover once is mistaken.

Comment: Conversely, you could argue that William doesn't count count as it's not like his claim was particularly worse than some others that would be used in history.  But usually when we use "occupied" in modern sense, we think of one country/culture controlling another.  That's not something that even really makes sense in the medieval world unless you're looking at the larger scale of the catholic vs. the muslim.

Comment: It would be like of Chelsea Clinton marched on Washington with an army of 10,000 to oust Donald Trump to secure her rightful place as descendent of a prior ruler.  If such a thing were to happen, we wouldn't say that the United States was "Occupied".

Comment: This gets a lot more tractable if you limit it to the more post-medieval era, when there were real nation-states

Comment: I've never heard of anyone making such a map. What leads you to believe it would be common enough that one could expect such a thing to already exist for any given geographic area?

Comment: It sounds like a great, fun project, but it probably doesn't exist. I would check out https://bigthink.com/strange-maps/yellowstone-eruptions?rebelltitem=3#rebelltitem3

Comment: If what you're looking for exists, this blogger might even know about it!

Comment: @GorttheRobot Yes, good point with postmedieval, although it would be nice to have more data on the amount of war in a given area.

Comment: @T.E.D There literally millions of different maps out there - so my thought was that any map I can make up probably exists (and otherwise I should even try to make it)

Answer (score 1):

Well... here's a [YouTube "The History of Europe"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UY9P0QSxlnI).  Something like 0.25 second per year or the like, running 11 minutes from 400BC.  So, if you were to look at a particular spot and take note of what happens to it, you'd more or less get what you want, assuming accuracy and that the scale suits you.  Note of warning: don't blink around periods like 1939 or 1989, the map jumps all over the place.

Reliability might be another thing.  They've got a list of sources and... one of them is another YouTube video.

Comment: In book form, there's Colin McEvedy's Penguin historical atlas series. It would even look a bit like that video, if you turn the pages really fast. :-)